# JQuery Slider Weird Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

My JQuery slider's `value` getter is not working.

`var value = $("#slider").slider("option", "value")`

It does not return the right value. My slider's range is from 1 to 5, if that helps. It returns odd values that do not correspond to the actual value. If I move it to the end and back again, instead of going 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, like it should, it does 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2. The 5 isn't even at the end, when I get to the end it says 4 but when I slide it one back it says 5!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When are you trying to query these values?

If it's during the `slide` callback you'll get the ***previous value***, not the current, and you should use the `ui.value` parameter instead.

Comment: Trust me, I was stuck on this problem for a long time.